# Remove Duplicate Amounts

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables with invoice detail and serial numbers.

Both tables have invoice number, but when I attempt to join using left or inner join the amount duplicates in each lines. I want to list down all the serials associated with my invoice # in table 1 without duplicating the amount each lines. I'm currently using MS Access.

Thanks for the help.

**Table 1**

```
Invoice# amount
001       500
```

**Table 2**

```
Invoice# serial
001      123
001      456
001      789
001      1011
001      1213
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Invoice# amount serial
001      500    123
                456
                789
                1011
                1213
```

**My Current Query Output:**

[image: my Current query output]

**Query:**

```
Select invoice.invoice,invoice.amount,tblmachine.serial
From tblmachine inner join invoice on tblmachine.invoice =invoice.invoice;
```

Comment: The desired output doesn't make sense to me. Can you please edit your question and explain how you expect the output is built?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, thanks for your response. I have made revision in table 1 and added my current query output for your reference

Comment: It's impossible to tell you why your query isn't working, because you've not posted your query. We can't help you solve problems with code we can't see, and we're not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to try to help, but you need to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Sorry about that.i have added my query now in the post

Comment: You can do that in a _report_. Specify _Hide duplicates_ as _True_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` for 2 queries.
The 1st will return the 1st row that you need and the 2nd all the rest:

```
select i.[invoice#], i.amount, min(t.serial) as serial
from tblmachine as t inner join invoice as i
on t.[invoice#] = i.[invoice#]
where i.[invoice#] = '001'
group by i.[invoice#], i.amount
union all
select null, null, t.serial
from tblmachine as t
where t.[invoice#] = '001' 
and t.serial > (select min(serial) from tblmachine where [invoice#] = t.[invoice#])
```

Results:

```
invoice#    amount  serial
001         500     123
                    456
                    789
                    1011
                    1213
```

Comment: Hi forpas, thank you for your suggestion. It works for me but if i have more than one records in table 1 having same invoice but different amounts it replicates the 1st serials then display the other serial afterwards.

Comment: *same invoice but different amounts* this is not what your question and sample data  are about.

Comment: Correct forpas, as mentioned your suggestion works great with my requirement. I just think additional scenario out of my question above.sorry if this troubles you.

Comment: Your additional scenario is a new requirement and you can post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do that desired output in query for multiple invoices.

Build a report and set textbox HideDuplicates property to Yes.

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity, actually this suggestion works but for large amount of records I'm having a problem exporting to excel from access.

Comment: Can export report. Exactly what is the difficulty? Why need export to Excel without duplicates?